# Workaround for issues with Coefficient in 10.0.2

Tags: polynomials

`Coefficient` is *Mathematica* 10.0.x seems to be affected by a bug. While in 10.3.1 the following

```
 Coefficient[Expand[ApartSquareFree[x/(y1 - x), x]*
 ApartSquareFree[x/(y2 + x), x]], y1 y2]
```

returns

```
1/((x-y1) (x+y2))
```

as it should, in 10.0.2 I get just `0`.

Is there a good workaround for this problem, if my code needs to run also on older *Mathematica* versions? Are there other functions that use `Coefficient` internally and would be affected by this?

Comment: actually, the `10.3.1` result might be a bug..

Comment: hmm, may be you are right. Versions 8 and 9 also return `0`. I contacted WRI (CASE:3500508), so I'm waiting for a statement from them.

Comment: According to WRI, this is in some way undefined behavior, as my original expression is not quite a polynomial, so that it's difficult to say what would be the "correct" answer. Still, in their opinion, the behavior of Mathematica 10.3.1 is more correct than that of version 8 and 9.

Comment: can we see their full response?

Comment: I don't think that it is OK to post private communication without the consent of all the participants. The case number is given above, so you could contact Kyle Martin from WRI and ask him to repeat his arguments, if you're interested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

10.1 gives zero as well. This is a workaround (in the sense of giving the answer you seem to expect) - I don't know how general but it works for this example.

```
expr=Expand[ApartSquareFree[x/(y1 - x), x]*ApartSquareFree[x/(y2 + x), x]]
```

> -1 - y1/(x - y1) + y2/(x + y2) + (y1 y2)/((x - y1) (x + y2))

```
Coefficient[expr /. y1 y2 -> y1y2prod , y1y2prod ]
```

> 1/((x - y1) (x + y2))

My feeling, this is *not a bug* because your input is *not a polynomial* in `y1,y2`, and so the docs don't say what to expect.  A message to that effect would be preferable to returning zero however. Note that `CoefficientList[expr,{y1,y2}]` appropriately gives the error `expr is not a polynomial.`

Edit - this may be a more robust way to extract terms in the given form of the expression based on their numerator:

```
Select[ List @@ expr ,
    MatchQ[ 
     CoefficientList[ Numerator[#] , {y1, y2}]  ,
        {{0, 0}, {0, _}}] &]/(y1 y2) // Total
```

> 1/((x - y1) (x + y2))

Another path is to substitute all the symbols as they appear in the term numerators:

```
 Total[(Numerator[#] /. { y1 -> \[FormalY]1 , y2 -> \[FormalY]2})/
      Denominator[#] & /@ List @@ expr ]
```

> -1 - [FormalY]1/(x - y1) + [FormalY]2/(
>    x + y2) + ([FormalY]1 [FormalY]2)/((x - y1) (x + y2))

This is now a polynomial in the `\[FormalY]` so you can use `Coefficient` and `CoefficientList` directly.

Comment: I think that `CoefficientList` is indeed the way to go. At least it would generate an error message if the underlying expression is not a polynomial, so that one catch it in time and take appropriate measures.

Answer (score 3):

I think there is a slight change in the evaluation of `Coefficient[]` and the other functions do not have any discrepancy in the two versions. However, it is to be noted that the answer $0$ is correct as well. I guess the difference in the two versions is that the expression is simplified in Mathematica 10.0.2. I think you should use `Simplify[]` before taking the coefficient.

In both the versions:

```
Expand[ApartSquareFree[x/(y1 - x), x]*ApartSquareFree[x/(y2 + x), x]]
```

yields

$-1 - \frac{y1}{(x - y1)} + \frac{y2}{(x + y2)} + \frac{y1 y2}{(x - y1)(x + y2)}$

If you use `Simplify` the expression becomes:
$-\frac{x^2}{(x - y1) (x + y2)}$

The coefficient of $y1y2$ is $0$ in this case.

Taking `Simplify[]` may be computationally time taking if the expressions are huge.

Comment: Check this out for dealing with Greek: http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1043/additional-useful-buttons-for-our-m-se-editor  Many of us use this tool to fix up posts with lots of `\[Alpha]`s in them.